# Perl regular expressions to capture parts of command output

Tags: regex, perl

Edited the question : I have added a third function. I have come up with a regex which seems to be correct . (1st and 2nd function work as expected. )

I have written a couple of functions which are in a library, and I call the functions from my test script. I'm having some issues with the regular expressions. Can somebody help me out with the regular expressions?

Function 1:

```
sub ipsec_version {
    my ($self)  = @_;
    my $cmd     = 'sudo -s ipsec version ';
    my $version = 0;

   #execute the command
   $self->execute($cmd);

   foreach my $line ( @{ $self->get_stdout() } ) {
        if ( $line =~ m/strongSwan/msx ) {
            $version = $1;
        }
    }
   return $version;

}
```

Function call:

```
$self->{'ipsec_version'} = $self->{'ipsec_obj'}->ipsec_version();
INFO('[Startup] ipsec version is  : ' .  $self->{'ipsec_version'} );
```

Actual output:

```
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ... line 37.
     ipsec version is  :
```

Expected output:

```
strongSwan U5.1.2/K3.16.0-30-generic
```

Command output:

I need the script to capture the expected output string from this

```
Linux strongSwan U5.1.2/K3.16.0-30-generic
Institute for Internet Technologies and Applications
University of Applied Sciences Rapperswil, Switzerland
See 'ipsec --copyright' for copyright information.
```

Function 2:

```
sub ipsec_status {

   my ($self,$connection_name) = @_;
   my $cmd = 'sudo -s  ipsec status ' .  $connection_name;
   my $status = 0;

   #execute the command
   $self->execute($cmd);

   foreach my $line ( @{ $self->get_stdout() } ) {
        if ( $line =~ m/Security\sassociations\d\()/ ) {
            $status = $1;
        }
    }

    return $status;
}
```

Function call:

```
   $self->{'ipsec_status'} = $self->{'ipsec_obj'}->ipsec_status('connection');
  ('[Startup] ipsec status is  : '  .  $self->{'ipsec_status'} );
```

Actual output:

```
INFO    [Startup] ipsec status is  : 0
```

Expected output:

```
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting)
```

Command output:

I need the script to capture the expected output string from this

```
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
      connection[3]: ESTABLISHED 3 seconds ago, 1.1.1.19[1.1.1.19]...10.81.1.50[10.81.1.50]
      connection{3}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, ESP in UDP SPIs: cb343e86_i abf6d1f2_o
```

Function 3 :

```
sub ipsec_restart {

    my ($self) = @_;
    my $cmd = 'sudo -s ipsec restart';
    my $restart = 0;

    $self->execute($cmd);

    foreach my $line ( @{ $self->get_stdout() } ) {
     if ( $line =~ /(Starting strongSwan.*IPsec$)/ ) {
          $restart = $1;
          last;
        }
    }

    return $restart;
}
```

Function call :

```
 $self->{'ipsec_restart'} = $self->{'ipsec_obj'}->ipsec_restart();
      ('[Startup] ipsec restart status  is  : '  .  $self->{'ipsec_restart'} );
```

Expected output : See the highlighted text below. 
I checked in https://regex101.com/ . My regex seems to be  correct. /(Starting strongSwan.*IPsec$)/

```
Starting strongSwan 5.1.2 IPsec


Actual output is  : 0
```

Comment: For function 1, What do you expect could change?  Anything other than what you highlighted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `$1` which is set only if there are *captures* in the regular expression that you are using. Also, you should add a `last` so that you don't go on searching for a matching line once you have found one. lastly, it is wrong to habitually add the `/m`, `/s` and `/x` modifiers to every regex match regardless of whether they make any difference, and a leading `m/` is only necessary if you are using something other than the default slash delimiters.

The first function should contain

```
for my $line ( @{ $self->get_stdout } ) {
    if ( $line =~ /(strongSwan.*\S)/i ) {
        $version = $1;
        last;
    }
}
```

and the second function is similar, although it looks like you're trying to match `Security associations` immediately followed by a digit, which isn't what is in the text. You also have a small `a` instead of a capital, which is fine if you also use an `/i` modifier. This captures `Security Associations` up to and including the last closing parenthesis on the same line. Is that what you need?

```
for my $line ( @{ $self->get_stdout } ) {
    if ( $line =~ /(Security\s+Associations.*\))/i ) {
        $status = $1;
        last;
    }
}
```

Comment: Regex for the second function captures the string partially.                        ipsec status is  : Security Associations (0 up, 0                            The following part is not being captured....             connecting). The expected string is  Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting)

Comment: @user3587025: Are you sure you have copied my code properly? The captured string must end with a closing parenthesis as it has `\)` in there

Comment: I'm learning regular expressions. Could you please explain the regex that u have used ?              /(strongSwan.*\S)/i    and   /(Security\s+Associations.*\))/i

Answer (score 0):

For function 1, assuming that all that changes is the version number, we can use

```
m/(strongSwan.*?) Institute/ms
```

as the regular expression.  This will match everything from `strongSwan` to `Institute`, in a non-greedy way, and store all of it except `Institute` in `$1`.

For function 2, we will use the fact that the unknown data is contained in parentheses.

```
 m/(Security associations \(.*?\))/
```

Comment: The OP's question is poorly formatted so that it appeared as though the command output as all on one line. I have amended the post to clarify it

Comment: @Borodin i have added one more function and formatted the questions for clarity. Let me know if it's not clear